# Remove summary option from this function (Blog post)

Tags: javascript, css

I have photo blog which displays random images from  JavaScript code which I am using in my blog post. My blog display all posts on the homepage with a thumbnail summary of that post. But since I am using JavaScript in the post, the summary displays the JavaScript code below the title of the post which looks awkward.

I found the function in the template which displays the thumbnail and summary of the post on the homepage.

All I want is to remove the summary option from this function.

```
function createSummaryAndThumb(pID) {
    var div = document.getElementById(pID);
    var imgtag = "";
    var img = div.getElementsByTagName("img");
    var summ = summary_noimg;

    if(img.length>=1) {
        imgtag = '<div class="crop"><img src="'+img[0].src+'" width="300px;" /></div>';
        summ = summary_img;
    }

    var summary = imgtag + '<div class="posting">' + removeHtmlTag(div.innerHTML,summ)   + '</div>';
    div.innerHTML = summary;
}
```

Comment: Can you not just remove div.innerHTML = summary;?

Comment: I did try to remove lines relating to summary, but the function just breaks,as the are images are displaying with their actual size not in thumbnail as before. I also did what told, that also result in the same.

Comment: i figured out removeHtmlTag(div.innerHTML,summ) + code needed to be removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i figured out removeHtmlTag(div.innerHTML,summ) + code needed to be removed.